# How to return one part of the string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

**How could I extract a part of the string or value in MySQL?**

*for example,*
i have the word `(Saturday Sunday)`
I want `(Saturday)`

Please help. Thank you!!!

Comment: How about `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get first word you can do so

```
select substring_index('Saturday Sunday',' ',1)

select substring_index(your_column,' ',1) from table
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9994/1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply with a demo, I would like to ask if this works if I have (Saturday Sunday Monday Tuesday) and I would like to return is Monday?

Comment: @user3563036 here is your [*demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e55d2/2) for the above point

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, one last question, What id my values are generated and not just Saturday Sunday, it can be any day or combination of days and the index must not be specified. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColName,1,LOCATE(' ',ColName)-1)
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do. 'field' is the column name. it will return all characters before blank.

```
SELECT LEFT(field,LOCATE(' ',field)) FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your input is `'Saturday Sunday Monday Tuesday'` and you want to find '`Monday'`.

Following example will demonstrate you to search a value and return the string in search if found else a zero length string is returned.

```
mysql> set @input := 'Saturday Sunday Monday Tuesday';

mysql> set @search_for := 'Monday';

mysql> select substring_index( 
    ->           substring( @rs, locate( @search_for, @rs ) ), ' ', 1 ) val;
+--------+
| val    |
+--------+
| Monday |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @search_for := 'Friday';

mysql> select substring_index( 
    ->           substring( @rs, locate( @search_for, @rs ) ), ' ', 1 ) val;
+------+
| val  |
+------+
|      |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your input may have altered sequence of day names, but the above solution need not be changed.